# matlab read h5 file produced with pandas

Tags: matlab, pandas, hdf

I have a csv file and I have transformed it in an h5 file with pandas:

```
data = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
data.to_hdf('file.h5', 'table')
```

Now I would like to read it with matlab.

How can I do that?

I have tried

```
data = h5read('file.h5','/g4/lat');
```

but I get:

```
Error using h5readc
The HDF5 library encountered an error and produced the
following stack trace information:

    H5G_traverse_real    component not found
    H5G_traverse         internal path traversal failed
    H5G_loc_find         can't find object
    H5Dopen2             not found

Error in h5read (line 58)
[data,var_class] =
h5readc(Filename,Dataset,start,count,stride);

Error in read_time_series (line 4)
data = h5read(data_path,'/g4/lat');
```

Comment: Is `/g4/lat` your dataset name?

Comment: pandas (via pytables) attaches a lot more metadata *on top* of HDF5. Matlab probably won't be able to read it. You may have luck using H5py, possible via [odo](http://odo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/hdf5.html), which understands pandas-style and native HDF5.

Comment: no the name is `data_path` the second argument was copied from the matlab documentation but I do not know its meaning

Comment: How about reading directly the csv-file in Matlab?

Answer (score 1):

You need to export with `format='table'`, see docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#external-compatibility).

This is can be read by various `R` packages and should be ok in matlab, as this is plain vanilla `HDF5`, which some meta-data attached (which is probably not read automatically).